# Magento 2.3 render first level subcategory grid with images on category page

Tags: grid, magento2.3.0, sub-categories

Hi I want to render sub categories grid with images.
Using below code in products.phtml but it renders all levels sub-categories.

```
<?php $category = $block->getCurrentCategory();          
  $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();         
  $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); 
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
  if(count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
 <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
        <?php foreach($category->getChildrenCategories() as $subcategory): ?>
            <?php $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcategory->getId()); ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info">
                    <?php if ($_imgUrl = $subcategory->getImageUrl()): ?>
                        <a href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                            <span class="product-image-container">
                                <?php $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />'; ?>
                                <?php echo $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($subcategory, $_imgHtml, 'image'); ?>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link" href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?= $subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>                                                               
<?php else: ?>
<?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I want to render just the next level child and similar on sub category page.

Comment: I have 5 levels of category and the above code is rendering 5th level children as grid on 1st level category page. whereas I want to render the just the next level children and similarly on next level children categories.

Comment: Actually the issue is , on first parent category page it is rendering all level subcategories under that category.